# Passing an existing object to JSP

Tags: jsp, object, servlets

I have a problem. In my app I have an existing object which is used in authentication (in my custom authentication provider class). This object is important because it has information about the connection. After authentication this object exists. Now I want to pass this object to a JSP page. I don't know how to do that.

I tried to write `doGet()` method for this class, make `request.setAttribute("object", object)` and get this object through `request.getAttribute("object")` on JSP but it doesn't work. Also I tried to use `<jsp:useBean>` but still it doesn't work. I don't have any other solutions.

Will you help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: please paste the the code you use to redirect to the jsp page

Comment: btw It would be better to store authentication related object in _Session_.

Comment: Ok, I will paste code tomorrow cause I don't have an access to it today.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I have a retrieveUser method in custom authentication provider where I connect to ldap server (ldapConnect class):

```
@Override
protected UserDetails retrieveUser(String username,
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication)
        throws AuthenticationException {

    log.entry("retrieveUser", authentication.getPrincipal());

    LdapUser userDetail = null;

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken userToken = authentication;
    String userName = userToken.getName();
    userName = userName != null ? userName.toLowerCase() : userName;
    String password = userToken.getCredentials().toString();

    if (password == null || "".equals(password)) {
        log.debug("retrieveUser", "no password provided");
        throw new AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException(
                "Invalid login or password");
    }

    // try to connect with ldap and check retrieved username and
    // password
    LdapConnect ldapConnect = new LdapConnect();
    connect = ldapConnect.connection(userName, password);

    if (connect) {
        log.debug("retrieve user", "correct connection with ldap");
        userDetail = new LdapUser();
        setUserDetails(userDetail, ldapConnect.getCtx(), username);
        userDetail.setLdapConnect(ldapConnect);
    }

    if (userDetail == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
    }

    return userDetail;

}
```

After that I want to get access to existing LdapConnect class (exactly to one attribute from this class) and I extend my LdapConnect class from HttpServlet class and I implemented doGet method:

```
@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.setAttribute("ctx", ctx);
    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/ldap_saved.jsp").forward(
            request, response);
}
```

Finally i try to get ctx attribute from LdapClass in my jsp file:

```
    <%DirContext ctx = (DirContext) request.getAttribute("ctx");%>
<%=ctx.toString();%>
```

But in this way I don't get an existing ctx object.

Comment: Ok i solved the problem. I changed my LdapConnect class to singleton class and getInstance method always returned my LdapConnect object which were created during the authentication.